# Applying [[no_unique_address]] to scope guards within function body

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to use a stateless scope guard

```
struct ScopeGuard {
    ScopeGuard();
    ~ScopeGuard();
};

void f();

int test() {
    ScopeGuard scopeguard1;
    ScopeGuard scopeguard2;
    // doesn't work:
    // [[no_unique_address]] ScopeGuard scopeguard3;
    f();
}
```

The scope guard itself has no state, I am only interested in the side effects of the constructor/destructor.

I want `test` to have a stack size of 0.
But `scopeguard1` and `scopeguard2` take 8 bytes of stack space each. This is because the `this` pointer needs to be unique for each instance of `ScopeGuard`, even if it is stateless.

Usually, I would want to use `[[no_unique_address]]` in this situation. But it seems `[[no_unique_address]]` only works for member variables but not for local variables inside functions.

Is there some other way to achieve this?
Why is `[[no_unique_address]]` only supported for member variables? Was this an oversight in C++20? Was it intentional? Would there be any issues with allowing this attribute also for local variables?

Comment: I don't believe a compiler needed that hint even pre-C++20. Did you *actually* check if the optimized function contains anything but function calls and the usual prolog? Member variables have object-model constraints and cannot be optimized without the hint.

Comment: And if you say the c'tor and d'tor aren't inline functions... given your guard has no state then it's a simple transformation into a guard with inline functions https://godbolt.org/z/5jzxje585

Answer (score 4):

> I want `test` to have a stack size of 0.
> But `scopeguard1` and `scopeguard2` take 8 bytes of stack space each. This is because the `this` pointer needs to be unique for each instance of `ScopeGuard`, even if it is stateless.

How do you know that they don't?

If the compiler can see that nothing in `ScopeGuard` actually *cares* about the value of the `this` pointer, and nobody actually tries to take the address of a stack variable of this type, then the compiler is 100% free to not give such a variable space on the stack.

Also, you've misunderstood part of the behavior of `no_unique_address`. Despite the name, it actually [*doesn't* allow two instances of the same type to have the same address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59109480/734069). It allows two instances of *different* types to overlap in member layouts. So even if you could declare those local variables with that attribute, the compiler could not given them the same address (assuming someone looked at the address at all).

`no_unique_address` was needed for member variables because C++ has specific rules for how a type is laid out, and each member needs its own region of storage distinct from all others. `no_unique_address` allowed members to break that rule, so long as the unique identity rule is satisfied.

For local variables, the compiler has the option to optimize the stack as it sees fit, so it doesn't need `no_unique_address` to give it permission.

And don't forget: `no_unique_address` doesn't provide any *guarantees* of anything either. It gives the compiler the *option* to optimize something away; it's *never* mandatory.